# Add http request into background functionality IOS

Tags: ios, swift, background

In my project I use [SwiftBackgroundLocation](https://github.com/yoman07/SwiftBackgroundLocation)
to integrate location in the background of the app (To use background location when the app close). The question is if it possible to add a function that make http request to my server (**http request in the background** that integrated with the background location, send the location to the server). Is it possible to add this to the background location or should I do it differently?.

Thanks a lot.